# Text disappears if adding styles to markdown text + Can't add background color to markdown text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, markdown

I'm having this very odd issue with React markdown.

Inside of this code:

```
<ReactMarkdown
    className={styles.reactMarkDown}
    escapeHtml={false}
    components={renderers}
>

    {content}

</ReactMarkdown>
```

I am trying to add a background color to the markdown text (`content`). Inside of `styles.reactMarkDown`, there is `background-color: #some-color`. Unfortunately, the background color doesn't get added. I've verified that the CSS rule is actually loading because the custom font in there is loading.

I tried to get around this using a `<span>` element:

```
<ReactMarkdown
    className={styles.reactMarkDown}
    escapeHtml={false}
    components={renderers}
>

    <span className="bg-postbg text-white">{content}</span>

</ReactMarkdown>
```

But then the text disappears. I've tried searching for a while, and nothing comes close to it. What am I doing wrong?

Here's an image of what's going on:

[image: A background is not being applied.]

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the `ReactMarkdown` with a div and apply the style to it.

```
<div  >
    <ReactMarkdown
       // apply background property inside this className
       className={styles.reactMarkDown}
       escapeHtml={false}
       components={renderers}
    >
       {content}
   </ReactMarkdown>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that and it has not changed. A background is not being applied.

Comment: @Xyphyn are you sure your css set up right. are you able to apply those css classses in somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. It is just in the React Markdown. Another thing to note is that I do have custom renderers. I'll try something with that.

Comment: @Xyphyn custom renderers is to add styling fo different elements. i think i got the issue. I updated the answer

Comment: Yeah, my assumption was incorrect. I tried to apply custom styles to the paragraph element to no avail.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "apply background property here"?

Comment: @Xyphyn Inside that classname, apply the backgroun

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241232/discussion-between-xyphyn-and-yilmaz).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was an idiot and didn't use my renderers correctly.
For anyone else stumbling upon this post,
add

```
const renderers = {
    p: (props) => <p className={styles.reactMarkDown}>{props.children}</p>
}
```

or whatever stylesheet you're using. I accidentally named it paragraph.